# Bash command stuck when a session started using tee

Tags: linux, bash

I've implemented a mechanism in my bashrc to capture my entire Bash terminal session, including the output, using the following line:

bash

```
exec > >(tee -a ~/.bash_command_log) 2>&1
```

However, I've encountered an issue when I attempt to execute the command bash from the same terminal—it becomes unresponsive. How can I execute the bash command in a terminal where a tee session has been initiated?

I've explored the documentation without finding a solution. Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's becoming unresponsive. It's just that the prompt is going into `.bash_command.log` instead of being visible to you. Try running a command, like `ls`, and you should see the output.

Comment: yes typing ls works. Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: Perhaps instead of rolling your own, you should look into the [`script`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) command.

Answer (score 2):

> when I attempt to execute the command bash from the same terminal—it becomes unresponsive.

No, it just doesn't issue prompts.

This is because by default, Bash checks at startup whether its standard input and standard error streams are connected to terminals, and unless both are, it runs in non-interactive mode.  Your standard error is not connected to a terminal, so you get a non-interactive shell. Non-interactive shells do not prompt.

> How can I execute the bash command in a terminal where a tee session has been initiated?

Under the circumstances, you can get an interactive shell by starting it with the `-i` option.  The purpose of that option is specifically to overcome the default decision about whether a shell is interactive.  Example:

```
 $ bash -i
```

You could consider defining `bash` as an alias for `bash -i`, but I recommend against that, as it will likely cause other issues for you.